# Super Key (Windows Key) Application Search does not show Application

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, search, plasma

When I press the superkey and search for vs code it doesn't show, although it is in my system. This has happened to me with all my applications:

[image]

Comment: We need more clarification. Did you just get Ubuntu? Did you just upgrade? Are you able to see your applications with other launchers?

Comment: I think MS package it with the name "code", not "vscode", did you try that? Do other searches work?

Comment: MS package with the name "code". I tried that  it doesn't work

Comment: I am not able to see applications with other launchers